# JSON Path for conditional based input

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a following JSON -

I need to fetch the data/id value where pcadCrewAssignID equals inputvalue ( e.g - FRETEST5)
I have tried with this $.data[.customFieldValuesExt[.pcadCrewAssignID but it is returning only the pcad numbers.
I have also tried with dependent expressions but that didn't work either.
I am trying to use the json-path to avoid any additional coding using java or Xpath query by converting the JSON to XML.
I have tested the expressions using jsonpath.com
I have referred the following links -
https://zappysys.com/blog/jsonpath-examples-expression-cheetsheet/

https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=d9cfeff2934dbceeJmltdHM9MTcwMzAzMDQwMCZpZ3VpZD0xMWQ4NzUyZC1mYjQ0LTY1YzYtMmVhNS02N2NmZmFkNzY0ZmMmaW5zaWQ9NTI2Mg&ptn=3&ver=2&hsh=3&fclid=11d8752d-fb44-65c6-2ea5-67cffad764fc&psq=json+path+examples&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYmFlbGR1bmcuY29tL2d1aWRlLXRvLWpheXdheS1qc29ucGF0aA&ntb=1

Thank you for the help.

Sugata

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the sample JSON -

```{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"65831806a718036480383f1b",
         "displayID":"CA.231220.00029",
         "customFieldValuesExt":{
            "pcadCrewAssignID":"FRETEST5"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"65831853a718036480383f2f",
         "displayID":"CA.231220.00030",
         "customFieldValuesExt":{
            "pcadCrewAssignID":"FRETEST4"
         }
      }
   ],
   "total":2,
   "lastUpdated":1703105616508,
   "joined":{
      
   }
}```